# isolated local min

Tags: calculus, optimization

$f(x)=x^2(1-sin(1/x))$

I will take the derivate and equal it zero.

But I find:

$f'=2x(1-sin(1/x))+cos(1/x)=0$

How to find a local min and show it is not isolated?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: i think it gives only a numerical solution

Comment: You question is to show that this function has a non isolated local min ?

Comment: can you get any information about the hessian in a local min? is it strictly positive or negative definite?